# how can i combine these two formula? any suggestion?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, cell, mode

Both formulas give me the correct results separately.
I am trying to have these two function in one cell.

```
{=MODE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5),A1:A5))}
```

and

```
{=MODE(IF(A1:A5<>B1,A1:A5,""))}
```

any suggestion would be wellcome

Comment: Please [edit] your question to apply the correction from below and add some sample data with expected results.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work as an array formula.

```
=MODE(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5), IF(A1:A5<>B1, A1:A5)))
```

Comment: Great, thanks Scott for the hint and Jeepad for the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=MODE(IF((ISNUMBER(A1:A5))*(A1:A5<>B1),A1:A5))
```

It is still an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. Since i have some #DIV/0! errors in my cells, it give "#DIV/0!"